# My SQL Count( ) 0 with only 1 table

Tags: mysql

So I have seen this done with multiple tables, but am confused as to how this would work with multiple tables. I want to select the number of correct entries in a tournament. This works except if a user got none right. Then it returns NULL. I want this to return 0.

```
Table-tournament_entries

Column  
=============       
id      
tournament_id           
game_id 
user_id 
username    
prediction      
correct
```

Here is the query that I run, I am hoping to return all users even the ones who did not get any questions right.

```
SELECT 
  tournament_id, username, user_id, COUNT(`prediction`)
FROM 
  tournament_entries
WHERE 
  correct = 1 AND tournament_id = 1
GROUP BY 
  username
ORDER BY 
  COUNT(`prediction`) DESC
LIMIT 0,10
```

EDIT: Sorry for all the confusion so when I run my query I get this

```
username    user_id     CorrectAns
mj          455              10
charlie     1                8
bill        2                8
doug        51               7
```

but there are users who are not show who have received 0 right.  When I run the queries suggested I receive the number of questions .

```
username    user_id     CorrectAns
mj          455              16
charlie     1                16
bill        2                16
doug        51               16
sydney      452              16
Joe         218              16
```

If you notice sydney and joe are not in the first output but are in the second one

Comment: I removed the `php` tag and variable from your question, as they have nothing to do with what you're asking. This is strictly a MySQL question. :-)

Comment: Charlie, instead of updating the question in comments to an answer, [edit] your question to provide it here. Please add a small sample of your data and the results you'd like to get from that data with your query, so we can tell what you're really asking here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments to the other answer, I think what you're actually looking for is something like this (although it's hard to be sure without sample data and output):

```
SELECT 
  username, user_id, Sum(correct) As TotalCorrect
FROM 
  tournament_entries
WHERE 
  tournament_id = 1
GROUP BY 
  username, user_id
ORDER BY 
  TotalCorrect DESC
LIMIT 0,10
```

Comment: this also produces the number of questions not the number correct don't I need somewhere WHERE correct = 1? When I try it with the correct = 1 it still does not produce the users who have none correct

Comment: See my edit - I think I might have figured out what you're actually asking (although I shouldn't be having to guess).

Comment: yes this worked, thank you very much, sorry for the confusion my mistake

Answer (score 1):

Use this query:

```
$query ="SELECT tournament_id, username, user_id, COALESCE(COUNT(`prediction`),0) as cpred
FROM tournament_entries
WHERE tournament_id = 1
GROUP BY username
ORDER BY cpred DESC
LIMIT 0,10"
```

[`COALESCE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) will return the first non-null parameter given to it.

Cheers.

Comment: Added doc reference for clarity.

Comment: It needs the `correct = 1` removed from the `WHERE` if it is to return the ones that didn't get any correct, doesn't it?

Comment: it depends what 'correct' and 'prediction' actually mean. Also thank to Brad, cheer bro.

Comment: I don't think so. The question says "select the number of correct entries", even if the user got none right. It stands to reason that `correct` is a boolean where `1` means true, so if you eliminate the ones that aren't equal to `1`, you can't count them. :-)

Comment: this made no difference, it still only returns users who have gotten answers right. Im not sure if I was clear but count become one when a user gets an answer right, sorry for any confusion.

Comment: When you have a comment to address to a specific user, you need to use `@` before their user name so it goes to their notification inbox. You see mine automatically, because they're posted to your answer. Charlie will see it, because your answer was to his question. I just happened to check back for something else and saw yours to me by chance. :-)

Comment: that returns the number of questions, in this case 16, sorry asked question the wrong way. When a user gets a question right the column correct changes from 0 to 1. I basically want to count the number of 1s for each user. If there are none I want it to output 0. Sorry for the confusion